# How to convert MovieClip into bitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, movieclip

My question is quite simple -
How do I convert a MovieClip (that is dragged from the library) into  bitmapData?

PS: I`ve searched a bit for this solution but the only results i get is the other way around - to convert bitmapData into MC/Sprite/bitmap

Comment: That really depends what you want to do with the converted MC - is a MC with more then one frame? cacheAsBitmap will not suit your needs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure the `MovieClip` on stage has an instance name and then you can do the following:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myMovieClip.width, myMovieClip.height);
bitmapData.draw(myMovieClip);

// And to actually see it 
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
this.addChild(bitmap);
```